# Error Module 'flutter_secure_storage' not found when try Product ->Build for -> Profiling

Tags: swift, xcode, flutter, product, release

well this error occurs to me when I try to make my app in production.
The app is created with flutter and I was able to create the apk for android, but when I try to do it for ios it won't let me.
The file that I am opening is Runner.xcworkspace and the problem is the import of a flutter library, it seems to me that I have to make some kind of connection with the pods.

[here is the error, I want to tell you that I do not want to run the app, but to make an installer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqDil.png)

The error that occurs when building a release (ie. `flutter build ipa`) and not when running a debug build is:

```
 /[REDACTED]/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:48:9: fatal error: module
    'flutter_secure_storage' not found
    @import flutter_secure_storage;
     ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    note: Using new build system
```

Answer (score 0):

For me regenerating `Podfile` in the following way solved the issue:

```
rm ios/Podfile && flutter build ios
```

See [Closed [ios][release] GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m Module not found
#43986](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/43986#issuecomment-576942084)